# BoofCV on Android - threshold() returns black image

Tags: android, boofcv

```
 Bitmap blurredBitmap = GaussianBlur.with(sApp.getApplicationContext()).radius(5).render(R.drawable.test_img_divider);
        GrayU8 imageGray = ConvertBitmap.bitmapToGray(blurredBitmap,(GrayU8) null, null);
        GrayU8 imageThreshold = GThresholdImageOps.threshold(imageGray, null, GThresholdImageOps.computeEntropy(imageGray, 0, 255), true);

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageThreshold.width, imageThreshold.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        ConvertBitmap.grayToBitmap(imageThreshold, output, null); // output is totally black.
```

R.drawable.test_img_divider:
[image]

blurredBitmap:
[image]

imageGray(after it was converted to bitmap):
[image]

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. The image is actually not black. The pixels all have a value of either 0 or 1. But 1 looks pretty much the same as 0 if you treat the image as something that could have pixel values anywhere up to 255.

One way to deal with this is to use `forEachPixel()` to multiply each pixel value by 255.